# Distributional derivative only generalization?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Suppose $H_1$ and $H_2$  are Hilbert spaces which lie between test-functions and distributions, i.e.
$$
\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}) \subset H_i \subset\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}),
$$
such that the inclusions are continuous. The derivative $d/dx$ can be viewed as continuous linear maps $D\colon\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\tilde D\colon\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ respectively and with this notation $\tilde D\restriction_{\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})}=D$.

**Question:** If $T\colon H_1\rightarrow H_2$ is bounded and $T\restriction_{\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})} = D$, does it follow that $T=\tilde D\restriction_{H_1}$?

---

An example for this situation would be the Sobolev spaces $H_1=W^{2,k}(\mathbb{R})$ and $H_2=W^{2,k-1}(\mathbb{R})$ and there the assertion is true.

I've tried to look at it abstracty, so to forget about the derivative and ask $D$, $\tilde D$ to be arbitrary continuous linear maps with $\tilde D\restriction_{\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})}=D$. Then the only (?) thing we can use is the density of $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R})$. But this does not seem to be enough.

Surely if also $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}) \subset H_i $ was dense  the situation would be clear. While this is the case for the Sobolev spaces above, I don't want to assume that because it fails if $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by $(0,1)$.
Another sufficient condition would be to ask $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\cap H_i \subset H_i$ to be dense. This is true for Sobolev spaces on $(0,1)$ but it is not true for  Sobolev spaces on badly behaved domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I am trying to follow a way I have in mind to prove your statement, but I would like to know if I am understanding correctly your question: if, by trying a *reductio ad absurdum*, I assume that $T\neq\tilde D\restriction_{H_1}$, does this mean that there should exists an isomorphism $\tilde{\tilde{D}}:H_2\to H_2$ such that $$T=\tilde{\tilde{D}}\restriction_{H_1}?$$

Comment: I don't see where this $\tilde{\tilde D}$ should come from. You also seem to assume that $H_1\subset H_2$, I didn't do that initially, but if it helps I'm happy to see your idea.

Comment: I have asked you more info since I would like to avoid [this kind of situation](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4123/what-if-i-posted-a-perhaps-nice-answer-but-to-the-wrong-question) (even if it was not bad at all for me). What I'd like to do is to see if your question can be solved by using a folclore result of distribution theory (recently proved by Langenbruch and Voigt) that *it doesn't exists a Banach space $B$ invariant under differentiation such that $\mathscr{D}(\Omega)\subset B\subset \mathscr{D}^\prime(\Omega)$*.